# Understanding what it takes to remove the hash # from angular routes

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

Before removing the hash sign, I had

```
mainApp.config(function ($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/page', {
        controller: 'Page',
        templateUrl: 'templates/page.html'
    })
    .when('/main', {
        controller: 'Main',
        templateUrl: 'templates/main.html'
    })
    .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/main'});

    //$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

and these worked fine

```
http://localhost:8080/index.html#/main
http://localhost:8080/index.html#/page
```

After removing the pound sign, I added to index.html

```
<base href="/">
```

```
<script src="/vendor/bootstrap-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="/vendor/javascript/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="/vendor/javascript/angular/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="/vendor/javascript/angular/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="/javascript/index.js"></script>
<script src="/javascript/controllers/main.js"></script>
<script src="/javascript/controllers/page.js"></script>
```

and to index.js

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

now hitting `http://localhost:8080` redirects to `http://localhost:8080/main`

but going to `http://localhost:8080/main` directly in the browser returns 404 and the other pages too

What should I do to fix the problem?

my backend is java

Comment: actually, # means "hash", on the telephone it can be 'pound'

Comment: but to address your problem, check the route to the HTML of your templates, it is likely that your HTML is not found. Also, check your console for errors.

Comment: there are no errors so debugging is really hard

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's expected. Here's what happens when html5 is not turned on:

- you enter the url `http://localhost:8080/index.html#/main` in the address bar
- the browser makes a http request to localhost:8080/index.html and gets the html page as a response
- the html page contains an angular application that is executed. The angular router parses the path after the hash (/main), and thus loads the associated view and controller

Now what happens when you enable html5 mode and load index.hml?

- you enter the url `http://localhost:8080/index.html` in the address bar
- the browser makes a http request to localhost:8080/index.html and gets the html page as a response
- the html page contains an angular application that is executed. The angular router parses the path (/index.html), sees that it doesn't match any route, and thus changes the location in the address bar to the default: /main, and then loads the associated view and controller. Changing the location in the address bar doesn't make the browser do anything other than adding a new entry in its navigation history.

Now, what happens if you hit refresh, or directly enter `http://localhost:8080/main` in the address bar? Well in that case, you're saying the browser: "please load the page at the url `http://localhost:8080/main`. So that's what the browser does: it sends an HTTP request to `http://localhost:8080/main`. Since the server doesn't have anything at this address, it sends back a 404.

Now how to make it work? It's actually quite simple: you need to configure the server to send back the index.html page when it gets a request for the path `/main` (and for all the other paths of the angular application). That way, the browser will load the HTML page, the angular application it contains will be restarted, the angular router will parse the path (`/main`) from the URL, and it will thus load the view and the controller associated to that path.

Comment: @JB NIzet can you explain the last part how to do that?

Comment: @The_ehT It all depends on the server, what technology you use, etc.

Comment: @JB Nizet I am using apache server. Actually, after couple of googling I got it working using `.htaccess` by rewriting `#/{url}` to `/{url}` .Thanks for the explanation in the answer. :)