# Angular Js HTML5 Mode not working

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to add HTML5 mode to my angular app to remove the "#" symbol. 
The issue is that it just doesn't work. My entire ng-view will not display! Here is my code:

```
var app = angular.module('app', [
    'ngRoute',
    ...    ]);
app.config(['$routeProvider, $locationProvider',
function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $routeProvider.
        when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/main.html'
        }).
        when('/raw-communication', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/raw-communication.html',
            controller: 'RawCommunicationCtrl'
        }).
        otherwise({
            redirectTo: "/404"
        });
}
]);
```

My url that I am using is localhost:8080. It's worth mentioning that everything works when I remove the code for html5Mode.

When I mean it doesn't work, I mean nothing shows up on the entire ng-view directive. For instance if I had this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
<head>
    <base href="/"/>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Stock App</title>
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    ...
</head>
<body>
<h1>Stock App</h1>
<div ng-view></div>

</body>
</html>
```

only the h1 tag will appear. The content that is meant to display is the partial from "partials/main.html".

The URL has not changed when visiting localhost:8080, but a 404 error occurs when visiting localhost:8080/raw-trades.

I have the following error in the console:

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.13/$injector/modulerr?p0=app&p1=Error%3A%20…Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A38%3A135)

No other 404 errors occurred in my network tab.

UPDATE 3:

This is not a duplicate, as the homepage should still be working.

UPDATE: [full error link](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/modulerr?p0=app&p1=Error:%20%5B$injector:unpr%5D%20http:%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.3.14%2F$injector%2Funpr%3Fp0%3D%2524routeProvider%252C%2520%2524locationProvider%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Error%20(native)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http:%2F%2Flocalhost:8080%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js:6:417%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http:%2F%2Flocalhost:8080%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js:38:7%0A%20%20%20%20at%20d%20(http:%2F%2Flocalhost:8080%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js:36:13)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Object.e%20%5Bas%20invoke%5D%20(http:%2F%2Flocalhost:8080%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js:36:283)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20d%20(http:%2F%2Flocalhost:8080%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js:34:498)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http:%2F%2Flocalhost:8080%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js:35:117%0A%20%20%20%20at%20s%20(http:%2F%2Flocalhost:8080%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js:7:302)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20g%20(http:%2F%2Flocalhost:8080%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js:34:399)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20ab%20(http:%2F%2Flocalhost:8080%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js:38:135)

**UPDATE:**

I have narrowed down my problem; the following works:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider',
    function($routeProvider) {
       ...
    }
]);
```

but this does not:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider, $locationProvider',
    function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
       ...
    }
]);
```

Regardless if I am actually using `$locationProvider`.

**NEW UPDATE**

It's meant to be

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
```

NOT

```
app.config(['$routeProvider, $locationProvider',
```

What a waste of an hour!

Comment: is your server configured to handle HTML5 mode?

Comment: Pleaaase. Don't just say "it doesn't work". Tell us precisely what you're doing, what you expect to happen, and what happens instead.

Comment: @Claies Configure my server? I thought it was all client side stuff. How do I configure my server? I'm using Jetty if that helps.

Comment: What is the URL displayed in the address bar? What is the code of the html page? Do you have any error in the browser console? Do you have any 404 or other error code in the network tab of the browser dev tools?

Comment: HTML5 mode uses PushState, and the server has to handle URL rewrites if you are trying to load any other page than `/`.

Comment: but even / does not work. Also if that's true can you tell me how to do this in jetty

Comment: @JBNizet Updated again

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJS HTML5 Mode - How do direct links work without server specific changes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17646843/angularjs-html5-mode-how-do-direct-links-work-without-server-specific-changes)

Comment: based on your updates, it seems like your app is failing to load your `angular-route.min.js` script, which causes angular to stop loading and not parse any HTML.

Comment: You can click the URL in the error message for a detailed description

Comment: See that's what I thought, but the ".when" stuff worked which is also part of the angular-route

Comment: Also read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26894769/understanding-what-it-takes-to-remove-the-hash-from-angular-routes/26897659#26897659

Comment: also, did you add a `<base>` tag in your HTML?  HTML5 mode requires it in newer versions of Angular.

Comment: I added     <base href="/"/> to the head tag as the first element but sill no luck

Comment: well the script error is definitely indicating that something is wrong with the angular script or a dependency, probably `angular-route`.  are you *sure* you are using a version of angular-route that matches the version of angular?

Comment: I'm using: "angular": "~1.3.13", "angular-route": "~1.3.14". I used bower update and everything. the ".when" works though, so clearly "angular-route" is downloaded properly

Comment: Can you post the actual error link (not the truncated version you see in the console)?

Comment: this should probably be moved to [chat]

Comment: nope i already have: var app = angular.module('app', [ 'ngRoute',  'appControllers', 'appFilters']); . Also my ".when" stuff works so clearly not the problem

Comment: Of course. Like I said before my ".when" stuff works so of course I have to have had it! Also how can I have a chat with you on the Stack Overflow Chat, Never used it before

Comment: Why don't you post your code instead of letting us guess?

Comment: I recommend you switch to the un-minified versions of your bower components while developing (ie, use `angular.js` instead of `angular.min.js`). You get better error messages

Comment: Fixed. Just a silly issue left lol. Found it due to your idea to remove the .min for better error msgs. This what happens when you work tooo late. Can you post your answer regarding the server issue and the base tag as an answer so I can mark it as correct as it did help!