# href with routeProvider loads a new page instead of binding the view

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I'm stuck with routeProvider. my links keep opening a new page instead of loading the template in the view.

My code is the following

```
raceApp.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'raceApp/createChallenge_view.php',
            controller: 'createChallenge'
        })
        .when('/createchallenge', {
            templateUrl: 'raceApp/createChallenge_view.php',
            controller: 'createChallenge'
        })
        .when('/findchallenge', {
            templateUrl: 'raceApp/findChallenge_view.php',
            //controller: 'findChallenge'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
}]);
```

My HTML looks like

```
<base href="/runkinlocal/wp-content/themes/wordpress-bootstrap-master/" />

<a class="menu-item select-runner0" href="#/createChallenge">
<a class="menu-item select-runner0" href="#/findchallenge">
```

When the page loads, the initial template is loaded, but then when I click on one of the links, a new page loads instead of loading the template in the view
( the page looks like http://test.com:8888/runkinlocal/wp-content/themes/wordpress-bootstrap-master/#/createChallenge)

I am working with Wordpress.

I'm looking forward to your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Working Example

---

> #### [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/SQulzLDXFsG17RjMnwbV?p=preview)

### Suggestions

---

#### 1. Your `href`s should not have `#/`

```html
<a href="createChallenge">Create</a> |
<a href="findChallenge">Find</a>
```

#### 2. Otherwise doesn't need `redirectTo`

```js
.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
      templateUrl: 'home.html'
    })
    .when('/createChallenge', {
      templateUrl: 'create.php',
      controller: 'CreateChallengeController'
    })
    .when('/findChallenge', {
      templateUrl: 'find.php',
      controller: 'FindChallengeController'
    })
    .otherwise("/");

  // configure html5 to get links working on jsfiddle
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

#### 3. Extra comma after last .when()

You have:

```js
    .when('/findchallenge', {
        templateUrl: 'raceApp/findChallenge_view.php',
        //controller: 'findChallenge'
    })
```

The controller is commented out but there is still a comma.

#### 4. You might need to configure html5

(see script.js in the [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/SQulzLDXFsG17RjMnwbV?p=preview))

```js
// configure html5 to get links working on jsfiddle
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

#### 5. You can add the base href like so

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  angular.element(document.getElementsByTagName('head')).append(angular.element('<base href="' + window.location.pathname + '" />'));
</script>
```

### Relevant Resources

---

I suggest checking these out:

- [`$routeProvider` docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider)
- [`$route` example](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route#example)

---

Let me know if that works!

Comment: I'd also suggest checking out `ui-router` instead of `$routeProvider` - https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router

Comment: Here is a relevant question to check out as well about HTML5 mode: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28787645/angular-js-html5-mode-not-working

Comment: That's an amazing answer. I will try to put all the parts together when I find some time, and I'll let you know if it works

Comment: @user3177506 it's bad SO etiquette not to mark answers as accepted when they solve your problem.

Comment: I can't believe I've never marked the answer. It's exactly what I needed at that time. Thanks!
However since then I've moved to ui-router which I advise for people who still work with angularjs