# Trying to separate HTML pages Angular

Tags: html, angularjs

I have tried to separate the HTML-files to make it more reusable, but it does not work unfortunately. Googled around and followed the tutorials, but nothing works, maybe I had overlooked something. To give you a clear overview of my issue, added entire module. Maybe there is some error in it. The codes run perfectly in index.html, but want to split that up into different html-files. The example below should be run in "wheretobuy.html" file. Anyone who could help me with this.

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute", "slideshow", "json", "accessoires", "wheretobuy"]);
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
  // $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
      templateUrl: 'pages/home.html',
      controller: 'HomeController'
    })
    .when('/accessories', {
      templateUrl: 'pages/accessories.html',
      controller: 'AccessoriesController'
    })
    .when('/wheretobuy', {
      templateUrl: 'pages/wheretobuy.html',
      controller: 'WheretobuyController'
    })
    .when('/service', {
      templateUrl: 'pages/service.html',
      controller: 'ServiceController'
    })
    .when('/forum', {
      templateUrl: 'pages/forum.html',
      controller: 'ForumController'
    })
    .otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/'
    });
});

app.controller('HomeController', function($scope) {
  $scope.message = 'Hello from HomeController';
});
app.controller('AccessoriesController', function($scope) {
  $scope.message = 'Hello from AccessoriesController';
});
app.controller('WheretobuyController', function($scope) {
  $scope.message = 'WheretobuyController';
});
app.controller('ServiceController', function($scope) {
  $scope.message = 'Hello from ServiceController';
});
app.controller('ForumController', function($scope) {
  $scope.message = 'Hello from ForumController';
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <script type="text/ng-template" id="pages/wheretobuy.html">
    <div class="row" ng-controller="TabController">
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
          <li class="{active: isSet}">
            <a href ng-click="setTab(1)" class="country">Asia</a>
          </li>

          <li class="{active: isSet}">
            <a href ng-click="setTab(2)" class="country">Europe</a>
          </li>

          <li class="{active: isSet}">
            <a href ng-click="setTab(3)" class="country">South-America</a>
          </li>

          <li class="{active: isSet}">
            <a href ng-click="setTab(4)" class="country">Oceania</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="#/">Products</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#/accessories">Accessories</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#/wheretobuy">Where to buy</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#/service">Service</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#/forum">Forum</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
</body>
</script>
```

Comment: i'm am not sure but looks to me like you forgot to register the routes and your a tag href look a little bit weird to me. because you are referencing #/pagesnames but didn't register this kind of path nowhere

Comment: My root file is in this case "wheretobuy.html", should I remove path name "pages" in this case?

Comment: found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28788443/href-with-routeprovider-loads-a-new-page-instead-of-binding-the-view) . looks like you shoud  not use the # symbol in your href

Comment: Plunkr would help

Comment: Your code is missing an outlet in your body tag for the router to write the templates into.  when using `ng-route`, you must have an `ng-view`.  The angular router replaces the inner HTML of the `ng-view` element with the contents of the file specified by the `templateUrl` for the specific route.  Also, your code in the body is missing the `angular-route.js` reference.

Answer (score 2):

Please check the below solution, the key points here are

1. Setting up the routes using `$routeProvider`
2. Bootstrapping the app using the `ng-app` directive.
3. Using the `ng-view` directive in the view to render the template.
4. Specifying the **id** of the html template created using the `text/ng-template` type to match the associated `templateUrl` property's value

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);

app.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
      templateUrl: 'pages/home.html',
      controller: 'HomeController'
    })
    .when('/accessories', {
      templateUrl: 'pages/accessories.html',
      controller: 'AccessoriesController'
    })
    .when('/wheretobuy', {
      templateUrl: 'pages/wheretobuy.html',
      controller: 'WheretobuyController'
    })
    .when('/service', {
      templateUrl: 'pages/service.html',
      controller: 'ServiceController'
    })
    .when('/forum', {
      templateUrl: 'pages/forum.html',
      controller: 'ForumController'
    })
    .otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/'
    });
});

app.controller('HomeController', function($scope) {
  $scope.message = 'Hello from HomeController';
});

app.controller('AccessoriesController', function($scope) {
  $scope.message = 'Hello from AccessoriesController';
});

app.controller('WheretobuyController', function($scope) {
  $scope.message = 'Hello from WheretobuyController';
});

app.controller('ServiceController', function($scope) {
  $scope.message = 'Hello from ServiceController';
});

app.controller('ForumController', function($scope) {
  $scope.message = 'Hello from ForumController';
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
ul li {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/angular-route.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#/">Products</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#/accessories">Accessories</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#/wheretobuy">Where to buy</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#/service">Service</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#/forum">Forum</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ng-view></ng-view>

  <script type="text/ng-template" id="pages/home.html">
    <h1 ng-bind="message"></h1>
  </script>

  <script type="text/ng-template" id="pages/accessories.html">
    <h1 ng-bind="message"></h1>
  </script>

  <script type="text/ng-template" id="pages/wheretobuy.html">
    <h1 ng-bind="message"></h1>
  </script>

  <script type="text/ng-template" id="pages/service.html">
    <h1 ng-bind="message"></h1>
  </script>

  <script type="text/ng-template" id="pages/forum.html">
    <h1 ng-bind="message"></h1>
  </script>
</div>
```