# Not getting the requested page after reload window using angular.js

Tags: angularjs

I am facing one issue.when i am clicking the `<li><a href="course">Course</a></li>` link i am getting the requesting page but when i am refreshing this page again it is not coming using angular.js.its shoqing me the error `The requested URL /Gofast/subject was not found on this server.`.I am getting my home page by typing the url `oditek.in/Gofast/`.I am explaining my code below.

> app.js:

```
var GoFastoApp=angular.module('GofastoHome',['ngRoute']);
GoFastoApp.config(function($routeProvider,$locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/',{
        templateUrl : 'view/home.html',
        controller  : 'homecontroller'
    })
    .when('/deptinfo',{
        templateUrl : 'view/info.html',
        controller  : 'infocontroller'
    })
    .when('/TimeTable',{
        templateUrl : 'view/time.html',
        controller  : 'timecontroller'
    })
    .when('/course',{
        templateUrl : 'view/course.html',
        controller  : 'coursecontroller'
    })
    .when('/subject',{
        templateUrl : 'view/subject.html',
        controller  : 'subjectcontroller'
    })
    .when('/hod',{
        templateUrl : 'view/hod.html',
        controller  : 'hodcontroller'
    })
    .when('/faculty',{
        templateUrl : 'view/faculty.html',
        controller  : 'facultycontroller'
    });
    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
      enabled: true,
      requireBase: true
    });
})
```

I am adding also base url in my index page.See the code below.

> index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="GofastoHome">
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <title>...:::WELCOME TO Channabasavashwara Institude of Technology:::...</title>

    <!-- PACE LOAD BAR PLUGIN - This creates the subtle load bar effect at the top of the page. -->
    <link href="css/pace.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="js/pace.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="lodash.js@*" data-semver="2.4.1" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/2.4.1/lodash.js"></script><script src="js/angularjs.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/angularroute.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="controller/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top"  style="margin-top:50px">
      <div class="container" style="width:1270px;">
        <div class="navbar-header navbar-brand">
        Computer Science & Engineering
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="/Gofast/">Home</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="/Gofast/" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Edit <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="course">Course</a></li>
                <li><a href="subject">Subject</a></li>
                <li><a href="/hod">HOD</a></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                <li><a href="/faculty">Faculty</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Department</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Time Table</a></li>

          </ul>
          </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>
<script src="controller/HomeController.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="controller/CourseController.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<base href="/Gofast/">
</body>
</html>
```

Here when i am clicking on the `course` option the required page is coming but when i am reloading the same page again the its throwing the above error.Please help me to resolve this error.

Comment: You'll find the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16569841/angularjs-html5-mode-reloading-the-page-gives-wrong-get-request

Comment: @IvanShulev : They all have given the answer based on Node.js.Here i am using angular with php and using Apache so how will i resolve this.

Comment: There is a comment on the accepted answer by Alcalyn with a link to an article about this problem with an Apache back end, does that help you?

Comment: @lukkea : which link you are talking about.

Comment: click on the link in the comment from @IvanShulev and then search in page for "Alcalyn" and you'll find it.

Comment: @lukkea : No, As per instruction i created the `server.htaccess.` file and placed it into root folder.In this file i wrote these `# Don't rewrite files or directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# Rewrite everything else to index.html to allow html5 state links
RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]` code and saved it.Still its not working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding what it takes to remove the hash # from angular routes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26894769/understanding-what-it-takes-to-remove-the-hash-from-angular-routes)

Comment: @JBNizet : check my all comment i have already tried what they are saing as i am using Apache server it is too confuse to me.

Comment: @satya your question has in fact nothing to do with angularjs. Delete it and ask another question, or edit it and reformulate it completely, and set the appropriate tags. Your question should be: how to make Apache serve index.html when the URL is /Gofast/subject? And it should describe how you configured your server and what you tried.

Comment: @JBNizet : ok i will do this.