# AngularJS otherwise not working

Tags: angularjs

I want to ask you for help in this code.

```
app.config(function ($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {

    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
        enabled: true,
        requireBase: false
    });
    $routeProvider
      .when("/", {
        templateUrl: "views/home.html",
        controller: "HomeController"
    }).when("/login", {
        templateUrl: "/views/login.html",
        controller: "LoginController"
    }).when("/register", {
        templateUrl: "/views/register.html",
        controller: "RegisterController"
    }).when("/users", {
        templateUrl: "/views/admin/users.html",
        controller: "UserController",
        requiresAuth : true
    }).otherwise({
        redirectTo: "/"
    });
}).run(function($rootScope, Session) {
    $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function(event, next, current) {
     if (next.requiresAuth && !Session.getIsAdmin()) {
         alert("You are not authorized");

         event.preventDefault();
     }
  });
});
```

when I go to non-existent address it shows err:

```
Error: No default engine was specified and no extension was provided.
```

, so the otherwise param doesn`t work, why not?

Answer (score 2):

This error comes from the server, not from angular. You need to configure your server to serve the index.html page for this "non-existent" address (and for all the existent ones too, BTW. Read [Understanding what it takes to remove the hash # from angular routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26894769/understanding-what-it-takes-to-remove-the-hash-from-angular-routes/26897659#26897659)).

Angular can't do anything if there is no HTML page and no application at all. Once the index.html is loaded from the server, the angular application will start, will inspect what the URL is, will detect that it doesn't match any route, and will then redirect to the home page.

Comment: Yes of course. Stupid mistake. Everything is ok. Thank you