# Clean URLs for Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to use clean url routing for my web app but everything I try doesnt work. Here is my app.js. Im not to sure how the location provider should be added in to the app.js but everything I try produces a 404. Please could someone point me in the right direction?

```
 .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
//Enable cross domain calls
    $stateProvider
        .state('main', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
            controller: 'MainCtrl',
            controllerAs: 'vm'
        })
        .state('about', {
            url: '/about',
            templateUrl: 'views/about.html',
            controller: 'AboutCtrl',
            controllerAs: 'vm'
        })
        .state('blog', {
            url: '/blog',
            templateUrl: 'views/blog.html',
            controller: 'BlogCtrl',
            controllerAs: 'vm'
        })
        .state('corparate', {
            url: '/corparate',
            templateUrl: 'views/corparate.html',
            controller: 'CorparateCtrl',
            controllerAs: 'vm'
        })
        .state('contact', {
            url: '/contact',
            templateUrl: 'views/contact.html',
            controller: 'ContactCtrl',
            controllerAs: 'vm'
        })
        .state('login', {
           url: '/login',
           templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
           controller: 'RegisterationCtrl',
           controllerAs: 'vm'
        })
         .state('register', {
            url: '/register',
           templateUrl: 'views/register.html',
           controller: 'RegisterationCtrl',
           controllerAs: 'vm'
        })
        .state('dashboard', {
             url: '/dashboard',
             templateUrl: 'views/dashboard.html',
             controller: 'DashboardCtrl',
             controllerAs: 'vm'
              })
        .state('useredit', {
             url: '/settings',
             templateUrl: 'views/useredit.html',
             controller: 'UserEditCtrl',
             controllerAs: 'vm'
              })
        .state('friendlist', {
             url: '/search',
             templateUrl: 'views/friendlist.html',
             controller: 'FriendListCtrl',
             controllerAs: 'vm'
              })
        .state('friendprofile', {
             url: '/profile/:userName',
             templateUrl: 'views/friendprofile.html',
             controller: 'FriendProfileCtrl',
             controllerAs: 'vm'
              })
        .state('resetPassword', {
             url: '/resetPassword',
             templateUrl: 'views/resetPassword.html',
             controller: 'ResetPasswordCtrl',
             controllerAs: 'vm'
        });

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise(function ($injector, $location) {
        var $state = $injector.get("$state");
        $state.go("main");
      });
})


.run(function ($rootScope, $state, ParseApi) {
  $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, next) {
    if (!ParseApi.isAuthenticated()) {
      if (next.name !== 'register' && next.name !== 'login' && next.name !== 'resetPassword' && next.name !== 'friendlist' && next.name !== 'friendprofile') {
        event.preventDefault();
        $state.go('login');
      }
    }
  });
})

})();
```

Comment: i think if you want to go back to your main  `$state` in your  `$urlRouterProvider` you should just go to  `otherwise("/")`

Comment: **what** does produce a 404? What are you doing to get it? You probably want to read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26894769/understanding-what-it-takes-to-remove-the-hash-from-angular-routes/26897659#26897659