# how to enable deeplinking in angular4

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular4-router

I am trying to implement simple routing in my angular4 app, but have an issue with the deep links not working..

for example, I have an About component and a Homepage (todos) component, my app.routing.ts file is as below:

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';

import { TodosComponent } from './todos/todos.component';
import { AboutComponent } from './about/about.component';
import { CallbackComponent } from './callback/callback.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [

  {
    path: '',
    component: TodosComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'about',
    component: AboutComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'callback',
    component: CallbackComponent
  }

];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

Now the navigation works for these components when i'm clicking in the app from a routerLink, but if I type the URL directly into the browser, i'm getting a 404..

This is breaking my callback from my authentication source :(

my app.module.ts file has imported the router file, but this still doesn't work.. how can i enable deeplinking here?

Comment: Hint: the 404 comes from the **server**. When you hit enter in the address bar, you're sending a request to the server. Angular is irrelevant here. Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26894769/understanding-what-it-takes-to-remove-the-hash-from-angular-routes/26897659#26897659.

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/deployment.html#!#fallback

Answer (score 0):

If you have an empty path route `''` with no children, you should use `pathMatch: 'full'`

```
  {
    path: '',
    component: TodosComponent,
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
```

otherwise every path will match and the router will search the (non existing) child routes for matches with the rest of the path.

As mentioned in the comments, if you use `PathLocationStrategy` (default), you need to configure your server to support it.

You can check if the server is the culprit by switching to `HashLocationStrategy`

```
export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, {useHash: true});
```

The routes look different, so don't expect the old routes (without `#`) to work when you enter them directly.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you might have resolved your query.

The solution for this is what i used the HashLocationStrategy.

```
RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, {useHash: true});
```

This results in all app url being index.html, followed by "#" and then the routing information.

Since you're always going to index.html, regardless of the route, you won't get a 404 for any valid URL.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a URL rewrite.  In IIS it would be something like this:

```
<system.webServer>
      <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Angular" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".*" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
```